# React route with /:id param gives blank screen

Tags: reactjs

```html
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
   
      <Route
        path={"/city/:id"}
        component={NewWebflowLanding}
      ></Route>

      <Route path={"/"} component={NewPage}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );



  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <ScrollToTop>{routes}</ScrollToTop>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
      <ToastContainer hideProgressBar={true} newestOnTop={false} />
    </>
  );
};
```

I have a basic app.js setup, but react does not recognise any route with :/id param. As soon as i visit the route the app crashes and i get a blank screen with "Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error" error

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh3Gb.png)

Comment: help us by putting what's in console

Comment: can you please provide sandbox link?

Comment: yes i have added the console screenshot